# when the dynamic link is opened from browser(especially in safari) it is always redirecting to the app store even though app is installed in iOS

Tags: iphone, app-store, firebase-dynamic-links

My URL is same as below, i will get this link to my mail from sendgrid and in iOS when i tap on this it always loads the browser first (safari most of the case) and opens in app preview page even though app is installed.

```
URL:<a clicktracking="off" href="https://{project_name}.page.link/?link=https://{project_name}.page.link/users/email_check/{{ $email_token }}&apn=com.{project_name}.app&isi={applestoreid}&ibi=com.{project_name}.app&efr=1">https://{project_name}.page.link/?link=https://{project_name}.page.link/users/email_check/{{ $email_token }}&apn=com.{project_name}.app&isi={applestoreid}&ibi=com.{project_name}.app&efr=1</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you access a dynamic link in a browser. It will intentionally not go to your app because the actions indicate that your intent is to open a web page.

If you have your custom domain from Firebase ie: `[your custom domain].app.goo.gl`, send it into your link like so:

`https://[your custom code].app.goo.gl/`

And then tap that link. Does it open the app, or does it go to Safari? If it goes to Safari, it means that you haven't configured your iOS app for universal links yet, which is needed to support opening your custom domain url directly in the app. In Xcode, go to the Capabilities tab, and ensure that you've added the universal link domain as described in [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html).

If you tapped the site address on the far top-right on iOS, it disables universal linking on that iOS app, until you long-tap and ask to open in the app again.

Second, you can't type in universal links into Safari's address bar and navigate to the app. Safari, by design, will open that URL in the browser. The easiest, most reliable way to test whether universal links are working is to put a universal link into the app, and tap the link from there.